# Align float divs to center but last not full row to left

Tags: css

I've got list with float items

```css
ul {
  height: 204px;
  border: 1px solid #f0f;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul:nth-child(1) {
  width: 299px;
}

ul:nth-child(2) {
  width: 399px;
}

li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li> 
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li> 
</ul>
```

The problem is that on some display resolutions there is up to 100px empty space on right side.

I need some solution that will divide margin to same parts (50px on left and 50px on right) but keep columns, so in second `ul` forth `li` should stay exactly under first.

**PS**

Because of the need to keep the alignment of the columns

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

is not suitable.

Mediaqueries for all possible resolutions are also not suitable.

Thanks for help

Comment: what about using display:grid or flex ? did you try ?

Comment: how can i use that? can you add an example?